# How to access logstash http input from other machine with EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, logstash, elastic-stack

I'm trying to setup logstash in an EC2 machine. But I'm unable to add data outside my ec2 instance (e.g. my local pc).

I'm trying this:

```
curl -XPUT 'http:/mypublicip:31311/twitter/tweet/1' -d 'hello'
```

But, I'm not getting any results.

When I try inside the EC2 machine like this:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:31311/twitter/tweet/1' -d 'hello'
```

It works fine.

This is my security rule:

```
Outbound
Type: Custom TCP Rule
Protocol: TCP
Port Range: 31311
Destination: ::/0, 0.0.0.0/0
```

This is my logstash conf file:

```
input
{
  http
  {
    host => "0.0.0.0"
    port => 31311
  }
}

output
{
        elasticsearch
        {
                hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        }

        stdout
        {
                codec => rubydebug
        }
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Are you adding data from your laptop to EC2 logstash instance?

Comment: Yes, for test purposes.

Comment: Then you should open the inbound of security group not outbound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the inbound of your security group since you want the external machine connect to the EC2 instance. Try this and see if it works.

**Inbound**

```
Type: Custom TCP Rule
Protocol: TCP
Port Range: 31311
Source: 0.0.0.0/0
```